# Как отсортировать список объектов класса по полю объекта python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, сортировка, объекты

Как отсортировать список объектов класса по полю объекта в python? Ниже представлен конструктор класса. self.__patients - это список переданных в конструктор объектов.
Как правильно сортировать этот список по одному из полей объекта. Например каждый элемент списка содержит поле address. То есть поле будет иметь следующий вид:
self.patients[i].address

```
class Polyclinic:
    def __init__(self, number, address, *args):
        self.__number = number
        self.__address = address
        self.__patients = list(args)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
self.__patients = sorted(args, key=lambda x: x.address)
```

Comment: иногда можно `attrgetter('address')` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже дополнил [@jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs), можно использовать модуль `operator`.

Пример:

```py
from operator import attrgetter


class Polyclinic:
    def __init__(self, number, address, *args):
        self.__number = number
        self.__address = address
        self.patients = sorted(args, key=attrgetter('address'))
```

Подробнее смотри [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).